# Find on Dreamweaver with regex exclusion

Tags: regex, notepad++, dreamweaver

In Dreamweaver, I try to find the word "none" without these expressions:
`display:none` and `display = "none"`

My last try is:

```
([\w ]*)(?!display:|display = ")none([\w ]*) but it found all words "none"
```

Comment: Could you explain what are you doing? Replacing something with something else? Also, try `\b(?<!display:|display = ")none\b(?!")`. Or [`\b(?<!display:|display = "(?=none"))none\b`](https://regex101.com/r/CGPTZZ/2).

Comment: Just search in my code, not for replace. your solution work better but still found display:none

Comment: Then I think the second regex above should work, please check. [It does not match `display:none`](https://regex101.com/r/CGPTZZ/3).

Comment: Dreamweaver doesn't allow the < between ? and ! so it found all word none if i remove the <

Comment: It means it does not support lookbehinds. There is no way to do what you need with the tool then. Switch to some more powerful text editor, like SublimeText or Notepad++.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i try in notepad++ and it works.

Comment: If you add the notepad++ tag to the question I will post an answer and we'll get some points.

Comment: tag notepad++ added :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Notepad++ 7.2.1, you may use the negative lookbehinds:

```
\b(?<!\bdisplay:)(?<!\bdisplay = ")none\b
```

Use it with *Mark* feature to mark all the occurrences you need to find and check.

**Details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(?<!\bdisplay:)` - there must not be `display:` whole word before the current position
- `(?<!\bdisplay = ")` - there must not be `display = "` whole word before the current position
- `none\b` - a whole word `none` (`none` is followed with a `\b` trailing word boundary)

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, i was doing some tests and your second solution doesn't work in fact (no return at all). But your third solution work perfectly, thanks a lot ! Ok in notepadd++ 7.1 too.

Comment: You know, NPP is using Boost regex library, there might be a discrepancy between PCRE regex tests online and what is actually available in Notepad++.